# Azure SQL Database - Indexing 10+ millions rows

Tags: sql-server, azure, indexing, azure-sql-database

I have database hosted on Azure SQL Database and below is the schema for a single table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Article](
    [ArticleHash] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FeedHash] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PublishedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ExpiresOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Summary] [nvarchar](max) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Article] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ArticleHash] ASC,
    [FeedHash] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

I have a few queries which I'm executing that are really slow since this table contains over 10 million records:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PublishedOn DESC) page_rn, *
      FROM Article
      WHERE (FeedHash = -8498408432858355421 AND ExpiresOn > '2016-01-18 14:18:04.970')
     ) paged 
WHERE page_rn>0 AND page_rn<=21
```

And one more:

```
SELECT ArticleHash
FROM Article
WHERE (FeedHash = -8498408432858355421 
       AND ArticleHash IN (-1776401574438488264,996871668263687248,-5186412434178204433,6410875610077852481,-5428137965544411137,-5326808411357670185,2738089298373692963,9180394103094543689,8120572317154347382,-369910952783360989,1071631911959711259,1187953785740614613,6665010324256449533,3720795027036815325,-5458296665864077096,-5832860214011872788,-2941009192514997875,334202794706549486,-5579819992060984166,-696086851747657853,-7466754676679718482,-1461835507954240474,9021713212273098604,-6337379666850984216,5502287921912059432) 
       AND ExpiresOn >= '2016-01-18 14:28:25.883')
```

---

What is the best way to index this table so that queries execute below 300 ms? Is it even possible on such big table? The Azure SQL Database edition is S3.

Also, a lot of DELETE/INSERT actions are performed on this table so any indexes should not affect performance of these...

Comment: you need to index on ExpiresOn column and publishOn

Comment: I also would add `FeedHash` into the same index as `ExpiresOn` added.

Comment: Also careful check of execution plan will tell you where table scan is performed and on what value. So try to replace these table scans with an index lookup.

Comment: To know the best way to index this table it is necessary to know the data distribution in this table. Such things as: how many different `FeedHashes` there are in 10M rows, how many rows out of 10M are left after the typical `ExpiresOn > ...` filter; what's the selectivity of `ArticleHash` column. In any case, any extra index would definitely affect the performance of `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements. You'd have to measure the actual impact - it may be acceptable.

Comment: This is the most basic indexing you can do. You need a tutorial. You will have this issue again and again if you don't understand the *first thing* about indexes.

Comment: Do You Update the FeedHash or ArticleHash on every Update Insert ?   Is the FeedHash contained in the logic of the ArticleHash Logic.

Answer (score 0):

First query would benefit from [native pagination](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) with `OFFSET` and `FETCH`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Article
WHERE FeedHash = -8498408432858355421 AND ExpiresOn > '2016-01-18 14:18:04.970'
ORDER BY PublishedOn DESC
OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

The second query might benefit from substituting `IN` list with `INNER JOIN` of a table:

```
DECLARE @ArticleHashList AS TABLE (ArticleHashWanted bigint PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @ArticleHashList (ArticleHashWanted) VALUES
    (-1776401574438488264),
    (  996871668263687248),
    (-5186412434178204433),
    ( 6410875610077852481),
    (-5428137965544411137),
    (-5326808411357670185),
    ( 2738089298373692963),
    ( 9180394103094543689),
    ( 8120572317154347382),
    ( -369910952783360989),
    ( 1071631911959711259),
    ( 1187953785740614613),
    ( 6665010324256449533),
    ( 3720795027036815325),
    (-5458296665864077096),
    (-5832860214011872788),
    (-2941009192514997875),
    (  334202794706549486),
    (-5579819992060984166),
    ( -696086851747657853),
    (-7466754676679718482),
    (-1461835507954240474),
    ( 9021713212273098604),
    (-6337379666850984216),
    ( 5502287921912059432);

SELECT ArticleHash
FROM Article
INNER JOIN @ArticleHashList On ArticleHash = ArticleHashWanted
WHERE FeedHash = -8498408432858355421 AND ExpiresOn >= '2016-01-18 14:28:25.883';
```

Creating indexes on dates should help a lot:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Article_PublishedOn ON Article (PublishedOn);
CREATE INDEX idx_Article_ExpiresOn ON Article (ExpiresOn);
```

Answer (score 0):

for first query I recomend this index:

```
create index ix_Article_FeedHash_ExpiresOn_withInclude on Article(FeedHash,ExpiresOn) include ( DateCreated, PublishedOn, Url, Title, Summary)
```

and second query shoud use clustered index seek, you must look at Actul Execution Plan what happends. Also I think you have bad clustered index because valuse looks like not growing but has to be random and probably index is very fragmented, you could check it with query

```
select * from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), object_id('Article'), null, null, 'DETAILED');
```

if avg_fragmentation_in_percent is between 5 and 30 then you can fix it by

```
alter index [clustered index name] on Article reorganize;
```

if avg_fragmentation_in_percent is higher then 30 then you can fix it by

```
alter index [clustered index name] on Article rebuild;
```

(if after reorganize nothing changes then you could try rebuild)